# Start method execution after authentication

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Angluar as client and Spring Boot as server.   Some providers will call  directly to my server in a particular (Get/Post) endpoint. If User is authenticated the execution of method will start normally ,if not user is redirected to login -ui (angluar-client) , After successful login user is redirected to home page ,but i want to start execution of previous request (Get/Post  singleSignOnServicePost ).How i can solve this ?

```java
 @PostMapping(value = ["/sso"])
    fun singleSignOnServicePost(
            request: HttpServletRequest,
            response: HttpServletResponse,
            authentication: Authentication,
            @RequestParam(value = "SAMLRequest") samlRequest: String) {
       //.......
}
```

```java
 override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(LoginUrlFilter("https://xxxx/login"))
                .and()
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers(LOGIN_ENDPOINT_SUFFIX)
                .antMatchers(OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT_SUFFIX)
                .antMatchers(SAML_ENDPOINT_SUFFIX)
                .antMatchers(TWO_FACTOR_DEVICE_SETUP)
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage()(LOGIN_ENDPOINT_SUFFIX).permitAll().successHandler( authenticationSuccessHandler)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LocalStorage` to store what is the endpoint requested before redirecting to user login at angular.

(or)

At server side create `session` and store the endpoint requested in `session` and then perform `authentication`.

Use the value stored in `session` / `LocalStorage` to hit the endpoint.